# Switch between multiple instances of the same app via alt-` in Windows 11

Tags: windows, window-managers

Alt-tab allows to switch between all of the opened windows, but I want to be able to hit alt-` when sitting in chrome (for instance) to switch to another chrome immediately. Is there any way to do it?
I failed to find a working solution.